# Getting "Dead Code" error when i try use for statement

Tags: android

Bassicly i want to print 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 incrementing when the user presses the next button - but it shows a warning on i++ saying its a "Dead Code", this is how i usually do for statements so im not sure whats going on. Any guidance would be appreciated

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.one:
         break;
        case R.id.Next:

            for(int i=1; i<11; i++){


                info.setText(""+i);

        break;

    }
```

Comment: If you fix your indentation, you'll see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a "Dead Code" issue because your

```
info.setText(""+i);
break;
```

After you setText() the first time, you break, unconditionally. Therefore it will never get the chance to increment i, and that's where the dead code is.

I think it's likely that the issue here is a mis-placed }

You probably want the break within the case, rather than within the for-loop?

Comment: Cheers cant believe i made a silly mistake like that -__- but now im encounting another issue, when i press the button it does not loop but instead just prints out what the i value is <= to

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the desired functionality is from your question - do you want to display "1", and then "12", and then "123"... or do you want to display "1", "2", "3" ...? If it's the second one, I would think you would want:

int x = Integer.parseInt(info.getText()) + 1;
info.setText("" + x);